# Is it true that $U \cap (W_1 \oplus W_2) = (U \cap W_1) \oplus (U \cap W_2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

**Let** $W_i (i =1,2)$ **be subspaces of** $V$. $W_1 \cap W_2 =0$. **If** $U$ **is a subspace of** $V$, **is it true that** $U \cap (W_1 \oplus W_2) = (U \cap W_1) \oplus (U \cap W_2)$?

**If it is true, is there any way to give a formal proof? If it is not, is there a hint for constrcting a contradiction or giving a counter example?**

Comment: No, it is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is false. Take $V=\mathbb R^2$, $W_1=\mathbb R\times\{0\}$, $W_2=\{0\}\times\mathbb R$, and $U=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\mathbb R\}$. Then $U\cap W_1=U\cap W_2=\{0\}$, but $U\cap(W_1\bigoplus W_2)=U\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: So this counterexample can be considered as a $y=x$ linear on a $x-y$ plane where $W_1$ is x-axis and $W_2$ is y-axis?

Comment: That's a way of looking at it, yes.